# Modified JSON object fetched from API is not properly defined on first load in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble with images not loading in my React app. I fetch JSON objects form a local api, but I need to expand each of these object with one field which is an image url retrieved from a different api. After the first fetch to the local api I call the other api to insert the url value. This is used to render an image in an imported element.

I use a search to do the calls to the apis, so the selection of images to be loaded changes when I input a different search string. My problem is that when I first input a string, all fetched JSON object are retrieved, but the image does not load and instead displays the alt text. When I console log each JSON object in the `MyImages` element, the object in the log **does in fact** contain a urlField with the valid url. However, if I do a conditional log of all urlFields that are `null`, objects with well defined urlFields are printed!

If I then force `MyMainElement` to reload, all images are loaded.

What is happening here, and how can I fix it?

```
const MyMainElement = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);

  const fetchUrlField = (items) => {
    items.map((item) => {
      fetch(
        `https://imageapi.org/?q=${item.objectId}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          item.urlField = result.value;
        });
    });
    return items;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (search.length > 0) {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/search?q=${search}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          return result;
        })
        .then((result) => {
          const l = fetchUrlField (result);
          setItems(l);
        })
        .catch((error) => setError(error));
    }
  }, [searchString]);

  return <MyImages items={items} />
}

const MyImages = ({items}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items && items.map((elem) => {
        return <li><img src=elem.urlField alt="Text" /></li>
      }}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look more like this:

```
const results = Promise.all(
  items.map((item) => {
    return fetch(`https://imageapi.org/?q=${item.objectId}`).then((res) =>
      res.json()
    );
  })
);
setItems((items) =>
  items.map((item, i) => ({
    ...item,
    urlField: results[i].value,
  }))
);
```

You can't modify arrays in state, you have to create new array so react knows that it changed